# Swift: usage of protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

I was reading [Link](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-singletons-in-swift/) and got a question about protocols.

Say, we have a protocol to work with network requests.

```
protocol NetworkService {
    func request(_ endpoint: Endpoint, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
}
```

Then we create something like

```
class NetworkManager: NetworkService {
    func request(_ endpoint: Endpoint, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    }
}
```

But couldn't we just add `func request(_ endpoint: Endpoint, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` to the class itself without usage of protocols?

I understand the theory and why they can be useful in the situation where you have multiple classes conforming to some protocol, say, `Flyable` and then there's a method `fly` and then some classes like `Bird` or `Plane` adopt this protocol and they have different `fly` function and then you can create an array of `Flyable` and do different things with it, but going back to `NetworkService`, I don't see how it can be useful? I'm still a novice and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Suppose you have a view controller that uses `NetworkManager` to fetch some data, and renders it in a table. You want to test that formatting/render logic in a test, but you're on the subway, underground, with no cellular data or WiFi. How do you run your test?

Comment: Why is it useful? [Dependency injection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  In the case of your link, they are using dependency injection to avoid singletons (globally shared state).  Global state can lead to unintended behavior, as nobody knows who else modified that state.  Anyway, read up on dependency injection to know why protocols are used in this way.  Calling `fly` on a `Flyable` doesn't require a dependency on wings, or on a jet engine - just on some unknown class conforming to `Flyable`.  The dependencies on wings/engine were injected along with the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do with class but it has its own problems like

- classes doesn't support multiple inheritance.
- you can't use with structs and enums like you do with protocols
- types you create will have tight coupling

For network class its useful for testing like creating mock network request instead of network manager by creating different network managers which confirms to NetworkService and if you want to add some new functionality to network manager you add new protocol and confirm to it.